# Laravel Get data from relationship's relationship table and select column?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have 3 tables

**Users Table**

```
+----+-------+----------+
| id | email | password |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | 1     | John     |
+----+-------+----------+
```

**user_details Table**

```
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------+
| id | user_id [FK_users] | first_name | last_name |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1                  | John       | Kevin     |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Posts Table**

```
+----+--------------------+----------+
| id | user_id [FK_users] | title    |
+----+--------------------+----------+
| 1  | 1                  | 1st Post |
+----+--------------------+----------+
```

Now i already created all the relationships in the models and now i can access the user_details table by below eloquent query it returns whole users table and user_details table but i only want to select first_name and last_name from user_details table how do i do that?

```
$posts= Post::with('city:id,name_en', 'user.userDetail')->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: so you means you want to get rid of `user` table, right?

Comment: Nope i want to access user_details table's first_name & last_name column (there is more columns in user_details table i didn't added here)through user.userDetail relationship currently it returns whole columns from user_details and user table

Comment: try with(['city:id,name_en', 'user.userDetail' => function($query){$query->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'id')}]);

Comment: @fatemehMajd it returns null for user_detail

Comment: that because `user_id` must be in select query, since it is the foreign key. that's why result was null

Comment: @TharakaDilshan thanks it works but it returns whole user Table can't we only select id from users table or not select anything at all?

Comment: @FatemegMajd  Thanks it saved me i replaced id with user_id now it works but it returns whole user Table can't we only select id from users table or not select anything at all?

Comment: you just wanna not select email and password, right?

Comment: @fatemehMajd Yes, of course

Comment: well, somebody answered it. I was puzzled myself :-D

Comment: @fatemehMajd Thank you very much for your effort some one answered below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will fetch all the 'post' attributes, 'user' `id`, 'user_details' `user_id, first_name, last_name`

```
$posts= Post::with([
    'city:id,name_en',
    'user' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id');
    },
    'user.userDetail' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
    }
])->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: How to fetch only few attributes from "Post" in this case or set alias for few of columns in Post ?

Comment: fetch only few attributes: `Post::with(bla bla bla)->select([field_name1, field_name2])->where(bla bla bla);`. Don't forget to includes required foreign keys when selecting.